# Refreshing Account Kit access token

Tags: javascript, facebook, account-kit

I am integrating [Facebook's Account Kit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit) to my webapp.

My node.js server exchange the authorization code received by the client to an access token that is valid for 30 days.

I wonder how can I refresh this token without letting the user login again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the /me endpoint will refresh the access token.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/graphapi#at-validation

Comment: Actually it says that it validates the token not refreshing it

Comment: It's not mentioned in the docs, but calling the /me endpoint will refresh the token as well.